# Add clickable and fixed subview to UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, static, uitableview, subview, adbannerview

I'd like to place an ADBannerView object onto my UITableView screen statically, what means that I want it to always stay above my toolbar (self.navigationController.toolbar), even when the user is scrolling the tableview. I've solved this by adding by ADBannerView as a subview to my toolbar and given it negative values for the frames origin:

```
[self setBannerViewSize];
[self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview:bannerView];
```

The only problem is: I can't click and open the iAd this way - I can see the banner but nothing happens when I tap on it.

Since I'm also using a refreshControl, the option to use a UIViewController instead of UITableViewController and add a tableView manually wouldn't work for me. Is there any other way I can get my ADBannerView statically showing in my table view controller AND still being tappable?

Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yay!! After all I succeeded in solving this (really annoying) problem by myself (and a lot of reading around)!

First, I found this really [world-changing post](http://www.herrray.com/uitableviewcontroller-and-fixed-sub-views/). Basically this post handles with the topic that a UITableViewController uses self.view for its tableView property, so overriding the tableView property (or synthesizing it manually) plus giving self.view a new view (from application) and adding tableView as its subview would make it possible to reach the *real* superview of tableView.

But this still didn't solve my problem, although I was sure it would, because it all made sense. My bannerView appeared in the right place (and was fixed) but it still didn't do anything when clicked. But there was a second minor thing I didn't know about:

As I read in [this post](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/75193-iad-click-not-working.html) the superview of a subview doesn't only have to be userInteractionEnabled but also have a non-transparent backgroundColor. Because my superviews background color was set to [UIColor clearColor] it all didn't work - but setting its backGroundColor to e.g. blackColor solved the whole problem: the bannerView got finally tappable! :)

So, my code is now looking like this:

```
@synthesize tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (!tableView && [self.view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
        tableView = (UITableView *)self.view;
    }

    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
    self.tableView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    [self resizeTableToFitBanner];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView];

    // some other code
}
```

Comment: world-changing post ;) JK -- cool you got it to work, the code looks good BUT I would not set the insets I guess (0 should be the default?) and i would inline setBannerViewSize i guess... make it more explicit and easier to understand

Comment: now that I think of it. I would just not subclass UITableViewController but UIViewController... would save you half the code ;) => myVC : UIViewController<UItableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> and done you are

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the suggestion with the 0, I'll edit this. Inlining my setBannerViewSize would bless the code up, since it's quite complicated how I do that. But to the UIViewController: as I posted above I also use a refreshControl, which currently only work in UITableViewControllers ... :)

Comment: @Dschee, thanks for the link to the "world-changing" post. I found that I could do the same thing in the storyboard. I deleted the table view from the table view controller and added a UIView. Set the controller's view property to that view, and then added a table view as the subview of that view. I still needed to add the tableView property in the .h and connect that up in IB.

Comment: @Dschee k, then Id rename the setBannerSize to ... [self resizeTableToFitBanner] or so :D setBanneViewSize implies its a setter for a property (IMO! only)

Comment: rdelmar, thanks, good to know. :)
@Daij-Djan: You're right, I'll do it the way you suggested. ;)

Comment: @Daij-Djan because UITableViewController has a lot of required functionality for the table than the basic UIViewController. Learn about 8 of the features by googling for "Recreating UITableViewController".

Comment: Replacing the table controller's table with a parent view is not a good way to do this. See the iAdSuite by Apple for a much better solution.

Answer (score 2):

BannerViewController in Apple's iAdSuite sample code solves this problem very elegantly:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a container view, and set things up in IB. You can add a tool bar and ADBannerView to the bottom of the view of your navigation controller's root view controller. Fill the rest of the space with a container view - this will give you an embedded view controller automatically. You should delete this one and then drag in a tableViewController and control drag from the container view to the tableViewController to hook up the embed segue.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but I don't use any IB at all, I do all programmatically. And I solved the problem in an other way, I'll describe it in a minute.