# MBProgressHUD not added to ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, mbprogresshud

I am using **MBProgressHUD** and when I am adding it to self.view it is not visible. However if I add it to tableview it is visible. In other Project I used to add it to the self.view and it's working correctly. In that view also tableview is present. Can you help me with this issue ?

Comment: put some code here..

Comment: + (void) showBusyIndicator:(NSString *) strMessage withTitle:(NSString *)strTitle toViewController: (UIViewController *)callingVC dimBackground:(BOOL)shouldDimBackground {
    //    NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible(TRUE);
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    hud_Progress = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:delegate.window animated:YES];
    hud_Progress.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud_Progress.labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", strMessage];
    hud_Progress.dimBackground = shouldDimBackground;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set the **layer.zPosition** of the MBProgressHUD view and now it's visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in your appDelegate file

```
+(AppDelegate *)getdelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}


-(void)showIndicator
{
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.window animated:YES];
}

-(void)hideIndicator
{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.window animated:YES];
}
```

And whenever you want to show MBProgressHUD in your viewcontroller write this

```
[[AppDelegate getdelegate]showIndicator];
```

to hide

```
[[AppDelegate getdelegate]hideIndicator];
```

hope it helps.

Comment: I am using it like below as mentioned by you, but the MBProgressHUD is not showing up.   AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:delegate.window animated:YES];
    // Configure for text only and offset down
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
    hud.labelText = textToShow;
    hud.margin = 10.f;
    hud.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = YES;
    [hud hide:YES afterDelay:3];

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to your `[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window]` since you just need only one instance of the HUD.

Comment: This is only a good idea if you want to block the entire window when the HUD is visible. Surely the user can use other parts of the app while something else is going on?

Comment: The above code is npt working. It is not visible on the view

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UITableViewController`, it's not allowed to add subviews to itself.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634707/add-clickable-and-fixed-subview-to-uitableviewcontroller) you can find a hack, which will fix this issue

Comment: NO I just using a plain UITableview